# TensorFlow2 beginner, recalculating after assigning new value

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow (using TensorFlow2). 
Trying to understand how to re-calculate a simple calculation, after re-assigning a value to variable. It sounds simple, but I'm having a hard time finding it in the new TF2 documentation. 
 
Simple example: define a tensor which is a sum two variables (3+4). Then, if I re-assign one of the variables, I'd like to re-use this "sum tensor" - making it re-calculate (without having to create a new "sum tensor"). Is there a way to achieve this please? thank!

```
v1 = tf.Variable(3)
v2 = tf.Variable(4)
sum1=tf.add(v1,v2)
print("Original sum 3+4:",sum1)   # This hows 7 as expected
v1.assign(9)
print("Sum after re-assign",sum1) # Fails, shows the old 7
```

Comment: You have to compute the sum again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to reassign the sum.

It's just like in plain programming:

```
a = 5
b = 10
c = a + b #yields 15

b = 100
print(c) #of course here, if you print c it would still be 15.
new_sum = tf.add(v1,v2)
print("Sum after re-assign", new_sum)
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry it's such a newbie question. I was hoping to achieve some reusable "function template" (in the example it's f(a,b)=a+b but in reality it will be more complex). That I can re-use by feeding different values for a,b and let it calculate different results... obviously I could write a simple python function, but I thought it would be more efficient to keep a reusable tensor structure without re-creating each time... anyway to achieve this please? Maybe in tf1 it corresponds to "placeholders"? Thanks